# Cannot access 'funct_name' before initialization works for pre-built JS functions but not component functions, Why?

Tags: reactjs, class, components, state

```
 //Ingredients
      const [enteredIngredient, setIngredientName] = useState("");
      const [enteredIngredientTouched, setIngredientTouched] = useState(false);          

      const enteredIngredientIsValid =
        enteredIngredient.trim() !== "" && hasAllowedChars(enteredIngredient);
    
    
      const hasAllowedChars = (string) => {
        const allowedChars = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
        return allowedChars.test(String(string));
      };
```

Now if I let this run as soon as the button is clicked that checks "**enteredIngredientIsValid**"
I get "Cannot access 'hasAllowedChars' before initialization" error.

But I write this (unwrapping the function)

```
const enteredIngredientIsValid =
         enteredIngredient.trim() !== "" && /^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(String(enteredIngredient));
```

Instead of whats above then **IT WORKS** (No "Cannot access 'blabla' before initialization"  error ), I'd prefer the cleaner way if its possible, to put it into a function,

Why cant I do that and is there any workaround?

Comment: Try move `hasAllowedChars` before `enteredIngredientIsValid`

Comment: Works fine, thanks for the quick solution

Answer (score 0):

A comment from @Viet explains it, just had to put hasAllowedChars() above the const declarations

```
 //Ingredients

      const hasAllowedChars = (string) => {
            const allowedChars = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
            return allowedChars.test(String(string));
          };


      const [enteredIngredient, setIngredientName] = useState("");
      const [enteredIngredientTouched, setIngredientTouched] = useState(false);          

      const enteredIngredientIsValid =
        enteredIngredient.trim() !== "" && hasAllowedChars(enteredIngredient);
```